# ansible.posix.firewalld fails with Polkit error

Tags: ansible, firewalld

This is probably an easy fix, but I'm not finding anything with my google-fu. Maybe pulling the wrong part of the error... Anyway, trying to just set a simple firewalld rule for inbound http.

This looks like some sort of permissions issue with the `become`?

I've set SELinux to permissive and found that this issue is still occurring, so I don't believe it to be SELinux related.

## Servers

All systems are running Fedora 34, fully updated. All machines also have the python3-firewall package installed.

1. Primary FreeIPA Server, (10.1.0.11)
2. Secondary FreeIAP Server (10.1.0.12)
3. Ansible Server (10.1.0.22)

## Trying to run...

```
[brandonyoung@ansible01 ansible-lab01]$ ansible-playbook -K -i hosts.yml playbooks/testFirewalld.yml
BECOME password:

PLAY [IPAServers] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************
ok: [10.1.0.12]
ok: [10.1.0.11]

TASK [Ensure that HTTP is allowed through the firewall] ***************************************
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.6:/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.fedoraproject.slip.dbus.service.PolKit.NotAuthorizedException.org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.info:
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.fedoraproject.slip.dbus.service.PolKit.NotAuthorizedException.org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.info:
fatal: [10.1.0.11]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.6:/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.fedoraproject.slip.dbus.service.PolKit.NotAuthorizedException.org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.info:
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.fedoraproject.slip.dbus.service.PolKit.NotAuthorizedException.org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.info:
fatal: [10.1.0.12]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
10.1.0.11                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
10.1.0.12                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

## Configuration

### hosts.yml

```
unitedStates:
  children:
    city:
      children:
        ansibleServers:
          hosts:
            10.1.0.22:
        IPAServers:
          hosts:
            10.1.0.11:
            10.1.0.12:
  vars:
    ntp_server: time.nist.gov
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

### playbooks/testFirewalld.yml

```
---
# This playbook will test some basic firewall rule enforcement using `ansible.posix.firewalld`

- hosts: IPAServers
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure that HTTP is allowed through the firewall
      ansible.posix.firewalld:
        service: http
        immediate: yes
        permanent: yes
        state: enabled
      become: yes
```

Output of `ansible-playbook -K -i hosts.yml playbooks/testFirewalld.yml -vvv` here: https://pastebin.com/ceskr5wJ

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Firewalld typically ships with a policykit definition. Perhaps yours is missing or altered. AFAICS, the firewalld <--> polkit communication is happening.

```
# ls -al /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.policy 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 49 Jul 30 10:31 /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.policy -> org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.server.policy.choice
```

The relevant interface is open by default with the stock configuration.

```
# cat /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.server.policy.choice 
[..]
  <action id="org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.info">
    <description>General firewall information</description>
    <message>System policy prevents getting general firewall information</message>
    <defaults> 
      <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>                                                 
    </defaults>                                                                        
  </action>                                                                            
[..]
```

You should check to make sure you don't have other polkit rules that may be causing the request to be denied. These may be provided by your distribution or admin.